# NotificationManager Error

Tags: android

```
//with context my code is not working
private void Notify(String notificationTitle,String notificationMesage){
        NotificationManager notificationManager=/8*(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);//li//ne75
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuiler=(NotificationCompat.Builder)new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_logo)
                .setContentTitle("WOBOT")
                .setContentText("Overdue Task\n")
                .setSubText("Task:a/c,\nGhaziabad\n,RS.200")
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_done, "Accept", null)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_clear, "Decline", null)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        Notification notify=mBuiler.getNotification();


        myNotification=mBuiler.getNotification();
        notificationManager.notify(23,notify);


    }
```

generates the below error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.acer.wobot_sample.Fragment_one.Notify(Fragment_one.java:75)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.acer.wobot_sample.Fragment_one.onClick(Fragment_one.java:67)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
12-04 18:58:09.005 16329-16329/com.example.acer.wobot_sample E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: edit your question and show code clearly.

Comment: What code is on line 75?

Comment: 'generates the below error:'. That is not a 'NotificationManager Error' but a NullPointerException. Wrong Title.

Comment: /*line 75*/ NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fragment you can get context with `getActivity()` method.